# Running three functions at the same time in Python doesn't work

Tags: android, python, shell

I am trying to simultaneously install Android APK on few Android Devices at the same time.

My idea is to invoke shell command that installs apk like:

```
adb -s DEVICE_NAME install APK &
```

Followed with `&` as it starts new terminal process.

My Python script should execute `install(device_name)` function at the same time. But it doesn't happen. There is a code:

```
from ShellHelper import *
from threading import Thread
import time
import datetime


shellHelper = ShellHelper()

apk_dir = "app-automation-integrationTest.apk"

def install(device_name):
    start_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    print('[{:%H:%M:%S}]: '.format(datetime.datetime.now())
          + "Installation started on device '" + device_name + "'.")

    install_cmd = "adb -s " + device_name + " install " + apk_dir + " &"
    shellHelper.execute_shell(install_cmd)

    end_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    print('[{:%H:%M:%S}]: '.format(datetime.datetime.now())
          + "Installation ended on device '" + device_name + "'. It took: " + str(
        (end_time - start_time) / 1000) + " seconds.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=install("emulator-5554")).start()
    Thread(target=install("emulator-5556")).start()
    Thread(target=install("emulator-5558")).start()
```

And log:

```
[23:31:50]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5554'.
[23:32:33]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5554'. It took: 42.671 seconds.
[23:32:33]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5556'.
[23:32:37]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5556'. It took: 4.451 seconds.
[23:32:37]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5558'.
[23:32:46]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5558'. It took: 8.98 seconds.
```

Throwing aside fact if ADB is capable of installing apks at the same time... what I would expect to happen is something similar to this:

```
[23:31:50]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5554'.
[23:31:50]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5556'.
[23:31:50]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5558'.
[23:32:10]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5554'. It took: 20.00 seconds.
[23:32:30]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5558'. It took: 40.00 seconds.
[23:32:33]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5556'. It took: 43.00 seconds.
```

What am I doing wrong?

// this worked

```
Thread(target=partial(install, "emulator-5554")).start()
Thread(target=partial(install, "emulator-5556")).start()
Thread(target=partial(install, "emulator-5558")).start()
```

And expected result:

```
[01:07:44]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5554'.
[01:07:44]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5556'.
[01:07:44]: Installation started on device 'emulator-5558'.
[01:08:00]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5558'. It took: 15.303 seconds.
[01:08:00]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5556'. It took: 15.571 seconds.
[01:08:01]: Installation ended on device 'emulator-5554'. It took: 16.748 seconds.
```

Comment: Why is `install` not callable? It's a function..

Comment: You needed to pass in the object, not the call. You specify the arguments to the function with `args` constructor attribute with the thread. A partial is not required

Comment: Thank you for explaining. How could I run it without using partial? Could you give me an example please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it without partial by using `args` param in Thread constructor:

```
Thread(target=install, args=('emulator-5558',)).start()
```